# $(document).ready(function() interfering with datepicker display?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a datepicker modified to show month and year only. It works. However, when I add a `$(document).ready(function()` to set the current month and year when the page first opens, only the left and right arrows (next and previous month) options are available (no drop-down menus; no other buttons). What's the issue?

JS:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({dateFormat: 'MM yy'}).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
});

$(function() {
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: 'MM yy',
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
      $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, 1));
    }
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" name="datepicker" style="color: #595959;" onclick="function1();function2();" onchange="function3()" />
```

Comment: There is, you can use the [defaultDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate) parameter of the object you provide to the `datepicker()` method. See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because you define one datepicker on the element, then immediately overwrite it with another instance with different settings. If you want to just set a default date value you can do this in a single document.ready handler on a single instance of the datepicker.

Also note your `onClose` setting is redundant as the logic in that code block is the default behaviour of the plugin anyway.

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    var defaultDate = new Date(); // = today

    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: 'MM yy',
        defaultDate: defaultDate, // set the default date of the picker
    }).datepicker('setDate', defaultDate); // set the text date value of the input

    // other code to run on document.ready...
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/u6gw9uoz/)

Comment: My mistake. Updated and added an example for you.

Comment: Working now! Thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad to help